# Scientific notation in Java

Tags: java, scientific-notation

```
    System.out.println(Math.pow(10 , -10));
```

I wrote this line and output should be **10.0E-10** , right? But instead it shows **1.0E-10** . What might be the reason behind this?

Comment: how? would you care to explain?

Comment: 1 * 10^-10 is what Java is giving you.

Comment: @FaizanAhmad Please consider accepting the answer that you think is the best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**10.0E-10**

means

10.0 x 10<sup>-10</sup>

But

```
Math.pow(10 , -10)
```

means

10<sup>-10</sup>

If you want a handy way to work with **10.0E-10** try

```
System.out.println(new BigDecimal("10.0E-10"));
```

> Output: 1.00E-9

or

```
System.out.println(Double.valueOf("10.0E-10"));
```

> Output: 1.0E-9

Which is best depends on which consideration is more important to you. Respectively: faithfully matching storage to presentation in base 10 or performance.

Answer (score 4):

The notation `xey` means x*10^y.

`Math.pow(10 , -10)` means 10 raised to the power -10, or 10^-10. This is equal to 1*10^-10, which expressed in the `xey` notation, is `1e-10`.